# Timeout on Specific IP Address

Tags: ipv4, ethernet, ipv6, internet

I'm thomas and I have a weird Problem with my Network/Internet Connection:

It's one specific IP(85.10.200.167) I'm unable to connect to.
The IP is public in the Internet and works well for many others.
It's like my router is blocking the IP or something.

**Environment**:

**Router & Router Status**: Hitron Technologies CVE-30360, Hardware Version: 1B, Software Version 4.2.8.9-IMD-KDG, Boot Version:PSPU-Boot 1.0.16.22-H2.8.11, DOCSIS mode: DOCSIS 3.0, Network Access: Permitted

**Client/PC**:Windows 10 Technical Preview Build 9841

**The Problem:**

1. Every connection Fails.
2. ping timeout (IPv6 & v4).

**What I tried so far:**

1. Reset Network: Problem persists
2. Restart Router: Problem persists
3. Reset Router to Factory defaults: Problem persists
4. Installed blank Windows: Problem persists
5. Set up a working Proxy on a Linux Server with `ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:8888 localhost -f`: Problem persists
6. Tried other Clients (Other PC, Smartphone): Problem persists
7. Connected PC throug 3G/4G Network to internet: Able to connect but not really a solution

I am out of ideas now. Anyone know what I'm supposed to do?

- traceroute: http://pastebin.com/kdUTxPTx
- packet capture using Wireshark: http://pastebin.com/EZjwgZUC

Comment: Have you tried a traceroute? How far do you get? Can you capture packets to see if anything comes back?

Comment: I tried with tracert command in differnet hops and timeouts [output](http://pastebin.com/kdUTxPTx)
looks like i'm stuck in my providers network ._.

Edit: command run as Admin

Comment: I captured  apckages from a ping command
result: [http://pastebin.com/EZjwgZUC](http://pastebin.com/EZjwgZUC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the router, **kabeldeutschland.de** is blocking that IP.

From the tracert is clear that the data packages are going out of your router. Call tech support of your ISP (Superkabel?) and ask them if they can reach 85.10.200.167

Comment: I called. they are looking for. I'll post when I know more :)

Comment: Called them twice. They rebooted my DSL connection. Still no success.

Comment: According to the tracert, the data packages go out of your router, they travel through equipments of kabel-deutschland.de where they drop the packages. Are kabel-deutschland.de and Superkabel the same company?

Comment: As far as I know kabel-deutschland is superkabel. They are working on. I'll try to get some details when they're done with it - just for interest.